# How to draw text in different languages using PIL

Tags: python, unicode, python-imaging-library

UPDATE (answer):
Found solution on my own. Just insert encode="UTF-8" as a parametr in `draw.text()` function, i.e.:
`font = ImageFont.truetype("18965.ttf", font_size, encoding="UTF-8")`

**Problem:**

I'm using Pillow library v 8.0.1 and I want to create an image with text. The only problem is that I cannot simply type my string as it's assigned to another variable, so I need to use an `f` prefix for string, i.e. `f'{some_value} не большой'`. As you can see in this example the string is in Russian and so should be the string assigned to `some_value`. I was told that all strings are unicode in Python 3, so I din't encode them, i.e. my solution looked like this:

```
el1 = f'{some_value} не большой'
img = Image.open('shopui.png', 'r') # 1842x1026
img_w, img_h = img.size
font_size = 12
font_color = (0, 0, 0)
background = Image.new('RGBA', (1440, 900), (255, 255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("18965.ttf", font_size)
draw.text((10, 80), el1, font=font, fill=font_color)
img.save('shopui.png')
```

This is the error message after executing the above-mentioned piece of code:

```
rror from callback <bound method SocketHandler.handle_message of <amino.socket.SocketHandler object at 0x000002A497216A00>>: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 6-10: ordinal not in range(256)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 344, in _callback
    callback(*args)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 80, in handle_message
    self.client.handle_socket_message(data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\client.py", line 345, in handle_socket_message
    return self.callbacks.resolve(data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 204, in resolve
    return self.methods.get(data["t"], self.default)(data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 192, in _resolve_chat_message
    return self.chat_methods.get(key, self.default)(data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 221, in on_text_message
    def on_text_message(self, data): self.call(getframe(0).f_code.co_name, objects.Event(data["o"]).Event)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\amino\socket.py", line 209, in call
    handler(data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\python bots\amino_faq\bot.py", line 125, in on_text_message
    upd_coins_and_level(difference, k, data.message.author.nickname, data.message.author.userId, activity,
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\python bots\amino_faq\bot.py", line 82, in upd_coins_and_level
    draw.text((10, 80), el1, font=font, fill=font_color)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 379, in text
    draw_text(ink)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 339, in draw_text
    mask = font.getmask(
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 148, in getmask
    return self.font.getmask(text, mode)
```

**Question:**

The obvious solution is to attach `u` prefix to the string (I've tried it with this kind of string: `u'some message'` and it worked!). However as you can see my string also consists of `{some_value}` that can be displayed only with `f` prefix before the string.

This is what I cannot figure out: how can I use both `u` and `f` prefixes before the string?

I will really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't think it will help you much, but I've edited the question

Comment: It's still incomplete. If complete it is an important source of information for debugging.

Comment: @KlausD. sorry, copied wrong logs, now fully edited. Still don't understand how it can be of use. My problem is a bit more general, related to PIL as a whole

Comment: You should add your answer as an answer and accept it!.